# Trying to send mail using Symfony Mailer with Office365 but keep getting SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: symfony, smtp, office365, mailer

I'm trying to get the mailer component of Symfony 5.0.0 to work with Office 365.

I can get it working in SwiftMailer using

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://smtp.office365.com:587?encryption=tls&auth_mode=login&username=#####&password=####
```

But when I try to use mailer with

```
MAILER_DSN=smtps://#####:######@smtp.office365.com:587
```

I get the following error

> Connection could not be established with host "ssl://smtp.office365.com:587": stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number.

If I try with just SMTP I get

> Connection to "smtp.office365.com:587" timed out.

Comment: Hi, did you solve the problem ? I have the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found for now was this.
[Issue Github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/34522)

Answer (score 0):

have you tired the office 365 email connector?