# send e-mail via office-365 with oauth

Tags: php, symfony, email, oauth, office365

we are trying to send a simple e-mail via office-365 and oauth.
In our code, we get the Token. That is fine. We can also send an e-mail with postman.
But we can not send just a simple e-mail.

We always get the errormessage: "Connection to "smtp.office365.com:587" timed out."

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Email; // Hier die Symfony Email-Klasse verwenden
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport\Smtp\SmtpTransport;
use PhpEws\EwsConnection;
use PhpEws\DataType\EmailMessage;
use PhpEws\DataType\MessageBodyType;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\Mailer;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface;

class OAuthController extends CommonController
{
    public function emailTest(MailerInterface $mailer)
    {
        // Konfigurieren Sie den OAuth-Client für Client-Credentials-Grant
        $provider = new GenericProvider([
            'clientId'                => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'clientSecret'            => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'urlAuthorize'            => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
            'urlAccessToken'          => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/oauth2/v2.0/token',
            'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
        ]);

        // Erstellen Sie einen Guzzle-Client
        $guzzleClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
            'verify' => false,
        ]);

        // Setzen Sie den Guzzle-Client als HTTP-Client für den OAuth-Client
        $provider->setHttpClient($guzzleClient);

        try {
            $accessToken = $provider->getAccessToken('client_credentials', [
                'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
            ]);
        } catch (IdentityProviderException $e) {
            // Failed to get the access token
            dump($e->getMessage());
            dump($e->getResponseBody());
            exit();
        }

        // var_dump($accessToken->getToken());
        // exit;

        // Verwenden Sie den erhaltenen AccessToken, um eine E-Mail zu senden
        $email = (new Email())
            ->from('XXXX@XXXX.XXXX')
            ->to('YYYYY@YYYYY.YYYY')
            ->subject('Test-E-Mail')
            ->text('Dies ist eine Test-E-Mail.')
            ->embed($accessToken->getToken(), 'AccessToken'); // Hier den AccessToken als Attachment einfügen

            $headers = $email->getHeaders();
            $headers->addTextHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $accessToken->getToken());


        $mailer->send($email);

        return new Response('E-Mail erfolgreich gesendet!');
   }
}
```

How can we send just a simple e-mail with the Baerer Token via office 365?

Thanks!

see above - our description

Comment: There is a sending limit - 30 messages per minute, see [Receiving and sending limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-limits?redirectedfrom=MSDN#receiving-and-sending-limits).

Comment: I found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59040023/trying-to-send-mail-using-symfony-mailer-with-office365-but-keep-getting-ssl-ope  who mention https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/34522 with associated PR to correct your problem. 
Which version you use or any update available ? Maybe misconfiguration with SSL or TLS ?